# Bicaption with multiline hanging caption and extra space

Tags: captions

I am using the bicaption package with the following style and I encountered a problem with the option format. Does someone know how to get a good way to proceed?

The current format looks like:

```
Bild 1.1:|--x--|Unterschrift
Fig 1.1: |--x--|caption
```

The extra distance |--x--| is managed by `format= X.Xcm` within the bicaption options. It works quite nicely. But when I am using a very long, in fact douple line caption I encountered a case like:

```
Bild 1.1:|--x--|Unterschrift...
sehr lang
Fig 1.1: |--x--|very long...
caption
```

I wanted to change this to

```
Bild 1.1:|--x--|Unterschrift...
                sehr lang
Fig 1.1: |--x--|very long...
                caption
```

This means a hanging format. But when I change `format=hang` of course the extra distance is gone an it will look like this:

```
Bild 1.1: Unterschrift...
          sehr lang
Fig 1.1:  very long...
          caption
```

Thank for any idea how to combine the two things!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR0pt,DIV12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm},hang]{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm}]{bicaption}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{labelfont=it, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, margin={0mm,0mm}}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\figurename{Test}}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{name=Test}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Fig.}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{4.0cm}{\hbox to 4.0cm{#1#2\hfill}#3\par}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{format=4.0cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[draft,width=\textwidth]{Beispiel}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
  \bicaption[indention=0pt]{Dies ist eine sehr lange Unterschrift in zwei Sprachen die über eine Zeile hinaus geht}{This is supposed to be a very long multiline caption in two languages}  
  \label{fig:Beispiel}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: \usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

Comment: Can you please show us a small MWE how you use bicaption?

Comment: How could we help you to modify the definition of the `caption` format `X.Xcm` if you don't reveal how it's defined? If you don't want to give us a MWE please tell us at least how `X.Xcm` is currently defined (with `\DeclareCaptionFormat`).

Comment: @Kantl are you the same who asked the question? The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\parbox` around the caption text might do the trick:

```
\documentclass[12pt,BCOR0pt,DIV12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm},hang]{caption}
\usepackage[labelfont=it, skip=-12pt, justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, margin={2mm,0mm}]{bicaption}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{labelfont=it, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false, margin={0mm,0mm}}
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand\figurename{Test}}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{name=Test}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Fig.}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{4.0cm}{\hbox to 4.0cm{#1#2\hfill}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-4cm\relax}{#3}\par}
\captionsetup[figure][bi]{format=4.0cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[draft,width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
  \bicaption[indention=0pt]{Dies ist eine sehr lange Unterschrift in zwei Sprachen die über eine Zeile hinaus geht}{This is supposed to be a very long multiline caption in two languages}  
  \label{fig:Beispiel}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]